# Why does dissociation of carbonic acid cause a decrease in pH?

Tags: ph

When a molecule of carbonic acid (H2CO3) dissociates, the two products are a bicarbonate ion (HCO3-) and a hydrogen ion/proton (H+). Because of the addition of a hydrogen ion, this process causes a decrease in the pH of the blood, and if someone breathes too slowly and doesn't quickly remove CO2 from their body, respiratory acidosis will take place.

However, *why* is it the case that the addition of this hydrogen ion lowers pH? While this might sound like a stupid question, it's also the case that the dissociation of carbonic acid produces a bicarbonate ion, which is a weak base. Therefore, the dissociation produces both an acid and a base in a 1:1 ratio. Therefore, the *concentration* of hydrogen ions relative to bicarbonate ions doesn't actually change. Given this fact, wouldn't there be no change in pH at all?

I read [a paper](https://watermark.silverchair.com/mki050.pdf?token=AQECAHi208BE49Ooan9kkhW_Ercy7Dm3ZL_9Cf3qfKAc485ysgAAAkEwggI9BgkqhkiG9w0BBwagggIuMIICKgIBADCCAiMGCSqGSIb3DQEHATAeBglghkgBZQMEAS4wEQQMFppu6o-EWEkTnw1AAgEQgIIB9PLdfgu2dzYkOEClT4lhiabSZO5Wp7JQJrKmXvaxRGSYsV-r2oNSydRIBkUE8nwS8o1mZLt5ce0JJMo6Y-tLtN-HIbmYQ-3XEF3YN2t-SQxrFKBzaZYrJzElaMlr0XfXMl1KXbxXfyNkBqQVPmUOaQJXIII9xEjqLU_kRHHdsbQ23IrpPfZ4IdodHFXRJOEKTAMyFbmJNouWbWtcjKDpX8RpZ_ny0SpBa9VGuFCXu3cV7oM82QrDiuOsm43Za6TGamhby_-QxT3BgAIHuta_PGiEE1rGikcmYMEzIfIYR2tXLJbEjBm-rP8ba8oXUahrmqdO1J0va6gpNaX15p3UOeA36uJI_Ztfn-7Jn1BFafmuiPdxbMeyJuwzZjjUuTwPPGfsxkmHpx3FQsYg3DFaTs2uUBeqskc32eno99EpI-RmsWKCCmZchK6jefm6RfXY0wDmwNI2FiavvKLc3Kc-Cn2Rq09M1mRO1vy30s6MwVJVQofYXpt8CUf212tyV3nApPTvVHe-ysOmhfXzyuu2AdgziXDD5pPvPBwz5qLIMRNcDIn_LMYNcmWnjPA9WG52JPjuGZlwFfFp2WKbj3HhMwmzt_PUZMXUhomcnCTNtVkXQGqNYgG9UO60u4D-WHilJ10FVgIEQRheqP9d_sVx6zGAOEOJ) on carbon dioxide transport which addressed some of my other questions but didn't touch on this precise point.

Comment: I've voted to close (migrate to chemistry). They may close it as well if they have a similar homework policy

Comment: @DeNovo This question doesn't concern any homework I have (my class only briefly mentioned the buffering system). Everything I ask (at least to this point) on the Bio Stackexchange concerns my personal understanding of these topics.

Comment: @Korvexius sorry, I know it's confusing, but here we consider "homework" to be the work, in the general sense, that you should do before asking a question. It's not specific to school assignments.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Any acid that releases a proton when it dissociates in water will also produce a conjugate base. We can conceptualize this as $\ce{HA <=> H+ + A-} $. In this particular example, $\ce{HCO3-}$ is $\ce{A-}$.  The strength of the acid is determined by the extent to which the acid, $\ce{HA}$, dissociates. This can be expressed using the [equilibrium constant](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Acid_dissociation_constant) for this reaction, which has a particular name, $\ce{K_a = \frac{[H^+][A^-]}{[HA]}}$, (where $\ce{[X]}$ is the concentration of $\ce{X}$ at equilibrium). The larger $\ce{K_a}$ is, the further the reaction moves to the right (or, as it is often expressed, the smaller the $\ce{pK_a}$, which is $\mathrm{-log_{10}}$  $\ce{K_a}$).

Here, the addition of any $\ce{HA}$ will produce $\ce{H^+}$ and $\ce{A^-}$ in an aqueous solution (the blood), and decrease the $\ce{pH}$. $\ce{A^-}$ is only a base insomuch as it can form $\ce{HA}$ by combining with $\ce{H^+}$. This can occur if you add (or, as occurs in the kidney, reabsorb) $\ce{A^-}$ with some counter ion other than a proton. Then you can drive the equilibrium to to the left, towards $\ce{HA}$, decreasing $\ce{[H^+]}$. Otherwise, $\ce{A^-}$ derived from $\ce{HA}$ will not drive the equilibrium one way or the other. $\ce{H^+}$ will still dissociate as determined by the $\ce{K_a}$.

Answer (score -1):

Bicarbonate will make the mudium basic ONLY WHEN it is bonded with some cathium that came from a strong base.

E.g. NaHCO3 is a basic salt because NaOH is a stronger base than H2CO3 is an acid. That way Na+ will stay completely dissociated while HCO3- and water will become H2CO3 and OH-.

H2CO3 is considered an acid because it ionizes in H+ and HCO3-. Some of the HCO3- will bond with water and form OH- and H2CO3 again. This is an equilibrium. But If we have only one HCO3- that didn't yet bonded to water and formed H2CO3 again, we will have more H+ in the medium, and it will be acid. In fact, there is a constant called Ka that measures how much HCO3- and H2CO3 are in a solution in a given time.